# In Swift: How do I decode this JSON (which has variable keys)?

Tags: json, swift

There is an API that supplies JSON data that I would like to use.  I've given a summary of the JSON below.  At the top level, the key to each record is a unique ID that matches the ID in the record itself.  These keys are integers in quotes (starting at 1, unsorted and probably not contiguous).

Reading the JSON isn't a problem.  **What is the Codable "Response" struct required to receive the data?**

```
if let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
```

---

The JSON

```
{
    "2546": {
        "id": "2546",
        "title": "Divis and the Black Mountain"
    },
    "1": {
      "id": "1",
      "title": "A la Ronde"
    },
    "2": {
      "id": "2",
      "title": "Aberconwy House"
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `Dictionary` with string keys.

Comment: Thanks for the responses below.  They were all very useful and I wish I could have "accepted" all of them (but I did upvote them).  I selected @Tharak's answer simply because he has the lowest rep score.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this once also, looks like whoever created this endpoint doesn't really understand how JSON works...
try this out and then just return response.values so you have a list of items

```
struct Item: Codable {
    let id, title: String
}
typealias Response = [String: Item]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a more dynamic version of `CodingKey`. You can read more about it here: https://benscheirman.com/2017/06/swift-json/

Check the section "Dynamic Coding Keys"

Answer (score 1):

The **`Codable`** type `struct Response` should be,

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let title: String
}
```

Now, parse the json `data` using `[String:Response]` instead of just `Response` like so,

```
do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode([String:Response].self, from: data)
    print(response) //["1": Response(id: "1", title: "A la Ronde"), "2546": Response(id: "2546", title: "Divis and the Black Mountain"), "2": Response(id: "2", title: "Aberconwy House")]
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a custom `CodingKey`, something like that:

```
struct MyResponse {
    struct MyResponseItemKey: CodingKey {
        var stringValue: String

        init?(stringValue: String) {
            self.stringValue = stringValue
        }

        var intValue: Int? { return nil }

        init?(intValue: Int) { return nil }

        static let id = MyResponseItemKey(stringValue: "id")!
        static let title = MyResponseItemKey(stringValue: "title")!
    }

    struct MyResponseItem {
        let id: String
        let subItem: MyResponseSubItem
    }

    struct MyResponseSubItem {
        let id: String
        let title: String
    }

    let responseItems: [MyResponseItem]
}
```

Not sure if the key of each item and the value of `id` are always equal, that's why there are 2 IDs in `MyResponse`.

And, of course, `MyResponse` should conform to `Codable`:

```
extension MyResponse: Codable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: MyResponseItemKey.self)
        responseItems = try container.allKeys.map { key in
            let containerForKey = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: MyResponseItemKey.self, forKey: key)
            let id = try containerForKey.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
            let title = try containerForKey.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
            return MyResponseItem(id: key.stringValue, subItem: MyResponseSubItem(id: id, title: title))
        }
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: MyResponseItemKey.self)
        for responseItem in responseItems {
            if let key = MyResponseItemKey(stringValue: responseItem.id) {
                var subItemContainer = container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: MyResponseItemKey.self, forKey: key)
                try subItemContainer.encode(responseItem.subItem.id, forKey: .id)
                try subItemContainer.encode(responseItem.subItem.title, forKey: .title)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how you can use `MyResponse`:

```
let jsonString = """
{
    "2546": {
        "id": "2546",
        "title": "Divis and the Black Mountain"
    },
    "1": {
      "id": "1",
      "title": "A la Ronde"
    },
    "2": {
      "id": "2",
      "title": "Aberconwy House"
    }
}
"""
if let dataForJSON = jsonString.data(using: .utf8),
    let jsonDecoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode(MyResponse.self, from: dataForJSON) {
    print(jsonDecoded.responseItems.first ?? "")
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
    if let dataFromJSON = try? encoder.encode(jsonDecoded) {
        let jsonEncoded = String(data: dataFromJSON, encoding: .utf8)
        print(jsonEncoded ?? "")
    }
}
```